# How to back up a line after a new line submitted by a user? Java

Tags: java, input, console

Suppose, you ask user to provide you some input via a console app in Java. They do and hit `Enter`. You get the string and do something in response. Say, you calculate some value based on the user's input and print it out.

How might I print out a response on the same line as user's input? I'd like to (possibly) delete a new line character and print out a response next to his input.

Please advise how to do this using Java.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot control the Console through basic Java.I think you can use JLine to control the Console.In java 6 u have java.io.Console class through which you can echo asterisk *'s when password has to be read.
http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/java_io_console_is_finally

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to implement this with the help of `jcurses` library and here is a demo of something you are looking for

```
import jcurses.system.CharColor;
import jcurses.system.InputChar;
import jcurses.system.Toolkit;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            CharColor printColor = new CharColor(CharColor.BLACK, CharColor.WHITE);


            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (true) {
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                InputChar c = null;

                do {
                    c = Toolkit.readCharacter();                  //Read each character
                    if (c.getCharacter() != 10) {                 //Do not print character if Return key
                        str.append(c);
                        Toolkit.printString(String.valueOf(c), i++, j, printColor);   //Print character as you type
                    }
                } while (c.getCharacter() != 10);
                Toolkit.printString(processInput(str.toString()), i, j++, printColor);
                i = 0;
                if (j == Toolkit.getScreenHeight()) {
                    Toolkit.clearScreen(printColor);
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String processInput(String input) {
        return " Input processed";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with ANSI-Codes. In Linux I never had a problem to use them, but on Windows, you have to install ANSI.SYS first.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class AnsiMove
{
        public AnsiMove ()
        {
                Random random = new Random ();
                System.out.print ("ESC[2J");

                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
                {
                        int y = random.nextInt (23) + 1;
                        int x = random.nextInt (79) + 1;
                        char c = (char) (random.nextInt (95) + 32);

                        gotoXY (x, y);
                        System.out.print (c);
                        pause (1);
                }
        }

        void pause (int p)
        {
                try
                {
                        Thread.sleep (p);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                        System.err.println (e);
                }
        }

        void gotoXY (int x, int y)
        {
                System.out.print ("ESC[" + y + ';' + x + 'H');
        }

        /** */
        public static void main (String args[])
        {
                new AnsiMove ();
        }
}
```